# Windows Hello not allowing to login

Tags: windows, windows-7, setup, pin, windows-hello

My laptop's battery died so I charged my laptop and I swtched it on. At the Windows login screen I entered my email address and password. Then my name popped up and the system is asking me to set up a pin. I clicked on Ok, then a One Time Passcode (OTP) came to my mobile number AND I entered that into the appropriate field, and it was verified.

Now, a pop up came asking me to set up pin. But it has only 'cancel' option. When I clicked on cancel option, it's again taking me to old page asking me to set up the pin and this cycle continues.

How do I create a pin when only 'cancel' option is being displayed? The screen is not showing a single option to help me get logged in.

Comment: Try restarting your laptop to see if that causes the changes you made to take.

Comment: Are you saying the window asking you to create a PIN is entirely empty and blank except for a Cancel button? Is there a field to type a PIN in? Have you tried just typing a PIN to see if the field lacks visible indicators?

Answer (score -1):

I disconnected from the internet and was able to login freely

Comment: That's a work around, but is it a solution? Firguring out what was going wrong and fixing it will give you a solution. Windows Hello should work fine whether you're connected to the internet or not.